# Why does this AJAX/Javascript function not work properly until the second time its called?

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation

I have been trying to wrap my head around AJAX requests, and currently implementing some server-side validation for a twitter-bootstrap wizard in Javascript.  I am experiencing some bizarre behavior where the function fails the first time its executed, but works as intended the second time.  I have simplified my code into this structure:

```
function do_ajax_validate($user,$email) {
    $.ajax({url: "checkuser.php?field=username&query=" + $user, success: function(result){
        if (result != 'Valid')
            {
                $("#userlabel").html(result);
                $("#userdiv").addClass("has-error");
                $("#userdiv").removeClass("has-success");
                $("#username").focus();
                is_good[0] = false;

            } else {
                $("#userlabel").html($user + " is available!");
                $("#userdiv").removeClass("has-error");
                $("#userdiv").addClass("has-success");
                is_good[0] = true;
                console.log(is_good[0]);

            }
    }});

    console.log(is_good[0]);    

    $.ajax({url: "checkuser.php?field=email&query=" + $email, success: function(result){
        if (result != 'Valid')
            {
                $("#emaillabel").html(result);
                $("#emaildiv").addClass("has-error");
                $("#emaildiv").removeClass("has-success")
                $("#email").focus()
                is_good[1] = false;

            } else {
                $("#emaillabel").html('Looks good!');
                $("#emaildiv").removeClass("has-error");
                $("#emaildiv").addClass("has-success")
                is_good[1] = true;
            }
    }});

    console.log(is_good[0]);
    console.log(is_good[1]);
    if ((is_good[0])&&(is_good[1])) {
        return true;
    }  else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Whenever I go into the console and try to run the function, I call it with a user/email that I know is available and get this output:

```
do_ajax_validate('available_username', 'available@email.address');
false
false
false
```

Whenever I run the exact same line, I get this output:

```
do_ajax_validate('available_username', 'available@email.address');
true
true
true
```

Then checking on a username/email that I know is taken, it returns the last values:

```
do_ajax_validate('taken_username', 'taken@email.address');
true
true
true
```

And (you guessed it) - executing the function again returns the expected results:

```
do_ajax_validate('available_username', 'available@email.address');
false
false
false
```

I've been trying different methods for hours now and getting these same bizarre results.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls run asynchronously in javascript. Your `success` callback will only be executed once the Ajax call returns, thus your `console.log()`s can be called before the `success` functions executes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a two solutions for this problem:

1. Work with result inside the callback you assign to success property. Try to console result under the success property
2. use `async: false` under AJAX call like:

> $.ajax({
>          url: "checkuser.php?field=username&query=" + $user, 
>          async: false,
>          success: function(result){
>          console.log("result")
>          }    });